# BelongsToMany with BelongsToMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I need to take data from a relation belongsToMany with belongsToMany, it would come to be so: A->B->C in my model would be providers->caption->eventType, so y need to take all providers from an event type.

model looks like:

Providers Model

```
Class Provider extends Model {
   public function captions() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Caption::class);
   }
}
```

Captions Model

```
Class Caption extend Model {
   public function event_type() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Event_type::class);
   }
   public function providers() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Provider::class);
   }
}
```

Event Type Model

```
Class Event_type extends Model {
   public function captions() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Caption::class);
   }
}
```

Database looks like:

**providers**

id

name

**event_type**

id

name

**captions**

id

name

**caption_event_type**

caption_id

event_type_id

**caption_provider**

caption_id

provider_id

Thnks.

Comment: Please add your relations and/or models, else there is no way to help you.

Comment: The model is the same as the one commented on there the partner Saumya Rastogi, thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding our Model Structure should goes like this:

```
class Provider extends Model {
    public function captions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Caption::class);
    }
}

class EventType extends Model {
    public function captions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Caption::class);
    }
}

class Caption extends Model {
    public function providers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Provider::class);
    }

    public function eventTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EventType::class);
    }
}
```

and to get all the `providers` for a `EventType`, you get it like this:

```
$captions = EventType::find(1)->captions;

foreach($captions as $caption)
{
    $providers_arr[] = $caption->providers;
}

$providers_collection = collect($providers_arr)->unique();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, As you said so is how I have the relationships in the model, but when I want to bring the data through $event->captions ()->providers I get this error: Undefined property: Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Collection :: $providers

Comment: Oh thats my bad, see my updated answer above!

Comment: Thanks brother, it helped me a lot